# Layout positions in android app not scaling properly for different devices

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, scaling

I designed my app using the android emulator with the device set to Nexus 5. I got all of the images in my app to line up nicely

[on a *Nexus 5*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oKDs.png)

however when I then tried testing it with the emulator set to other devices: a Nexus 6, 7 and 9, all of the x and y positions did not scale properly in relation to the background image.

[on a *Nexus 6*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD1y3.png)

Here is my xml code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spriteLayout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25dp"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/AustraliaLayout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="40px"
        android:minHeight="40px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Fishes1Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="20px"
        android:minHeight="20px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Fishes3Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Fishes4Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Fishes5Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="40px"
        android:minHeight="40px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Fishes6Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="15px"
        android:minHeight="15px"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/Large_Z_Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="12px"
        android:minHeight="12px"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/Medium_Z_Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="6px"
        android:minHeight="6px"
        android:layout_width="6dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/Small_Z_Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="35px"
        android:minHeight="35px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/WombatLayout1" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ToadLayout1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="40px"
            android:minHeight="40px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/ToadLayout2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/KangarooLayout1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="40px"
            android:minHeight="40px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/KangarooLayout2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="35px"
        android:minHeight="35px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SnakeLayout1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="50px"
            android:minHeight="50px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/SnakeLayout2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="40px"
        android:minHeight="40px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BirdLayout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Marker1Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Marker2Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Marker3Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Marker4Layout" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CarMarkerLayout" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and here is where I handled the layouts programmatically:

```
Australia = new ImageView( this );
        Australia.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.australia );
        Australia.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;  
        AustraliaLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.AustraliaLayout );
        AustraliaLayout.AddView( Australia );

        Fishes1 = new ImageView( this );
        Fishes1.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.fishes1_sprite );
        Fishes1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        Fishes1Layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Fishes1Layout );
        Fishes1Layout.AddView( Fishes1 );
        Fishes1Layout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 133.33 ) );
        Fishes1Layout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 323.5 ) );

        Fishes2 = new ImageView( this );
        Fishes2.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.fishes2_sprite );
        Fishes2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        Fishes2Layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Fishes2Layout );
        Fishes2Layout.AddView( Fishes2 );
        Fishes2Layout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 50 ) );
        Fishes2Layout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 350 ) );

        Fishes3 = new ImageView( this );
        Fishes3.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.fishes3_sprite );
        Fishes3.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        Fishes3Layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Fishes3Layout );
        Fishes3Layout.AddView( Fishes3 );
        Fishes3Layout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 303.33 ) );
        Fishes3Layout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 170 ) );

        Fishes4 = new ImageView( this );
        Fishes4.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.fishes4_sprite );
        Fishes4.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        Fishes4Layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Fishes4Layout );
        Fishes4Layout.AddView( Fishes4 );
        Fishes4Layout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 100 ) );
        Fishes4Layout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 116.67 ) );

        Fishes5 = new ImageView( this );
        Fishes5.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.fishes4_sprite );
        Fishes5.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        Fishes5Layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Fishes5Layout );
        Fishes5Layout.AddView( Fishes5 );
        Fishes5Layout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 303.33 ) );
        Fishes5Layout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 360 ) );

        Fishes6 = new ImageView( this );
        Fishes6.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.fishes1_sprite );
        Fishes6.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        Fishes6Layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Fishes6Layout );
        Fishes6Layout.AddView( Fishes6 );
        Fishes6Layout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 26.67 ) );
        Fishes6Layout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 173.33 ) );

        Snake1 = new ImageView( this );
        Snake1.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.snake_sprite );
        Snake1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        SnakeLayout1 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.SnakeLayout1 );
        SnakeLayout2 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.SnakeLayout2 );
        SnakeLayout2.AddView( Snake1 );
        SnakeLayout1.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 120 ) );
        SnakeLayout1.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 253.33 ) );

        ZLarge = new ImageView( this );
        ZLarge.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.z );
        ZLarge.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        ZLargeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Large_Z_Layout );
        ZLargeLayout.AddView( ZLarge );
        ZLargeLayout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 258.33 ) );
        ZLargeLayout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 290.33 ) );
        // move down by 7

        ZMedium = new ImageView( this );
        ZMedium.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.z );
        ZMedium.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        ZMediumLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Medium_Z_Layout );
        ZMediumLayout.AddView( ZMedium );
        ZMediumLayout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 268.33 ) );
        ZMediumLayout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 307 ) );

        ZSmall = new ImageView( this );
        ZSmall.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.z );
        ZSmall.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        ZSmallLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.Small_Z_Layout );
        ZSmallLayout.AddView( ZSmall );
        ZSmallLayout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 264.33 ) );
        ZSmallLayout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 318 ) );

        Wombat1 = new ImageView( this );
        Wombat1.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.wombat_sprite );
        Wombat1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        WombatLayout1 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.WombatLayout1 );
        WombatLayout1.AddView( Wombat1 );
        WombatLayout1.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 236.84 ) );
        WombatLayout1.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 323.338 ) );

        Toad1 = new ImageView( this );
        Toad1.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.toad_sprite );
        Toad1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        ToadLayout1 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.ToadLayout1 );
        ToadLayout2 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.ToadLayout2 );
        ToadLayout2.AddView( Toad1 );
        ToadLayout1.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 261.67 ) );
        ToadLayout1.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 210 ) );
        ToadLayout2.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 13.33 ) );

        Kangaroo1 = new ImageView( this );
        Kangaroo1.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.kangaroo_sprite );
        Kangaroo1.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        KangarooLayout1 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.KangarooLayout1 );
        KangarooLayout2 = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.KangarooLayout2 );
        KangarooLayout2.AddView( Kangaroo1 );
        KangarooLayout1.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 30 ) );
        KangarooLayout1.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 223.33 ) );
        KangarooLayout2.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 13.33 ) );

        Bird = new ImageView( this );
        Bird.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.bird_sprite );
        Bird.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
        BirdLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>( Resource.Id.BirdLayout );
        BirdLayout.AddView( Bird );
        BirdLayout.SetX( DP_to_Pixel( 150 ) );
        BirdLayout.SetY( DP_to_Pixel( 170 ) );
```

Finally, I created a method to convert the number of pixels to dp, which I thought could solve the problem, however its still not working correctly:

```
private int DP_to_Pixel( double dp )
{
    return (int) ( dp * Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density );
}
```

I've very new to programming, and I've tried everything I can think of to correct the issue. Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use dp instead of px

Comment: Thanks Mohd, but as I mentioned at the bottom of my post I did convert the pixels to dp

Comment: You are converting dp to px , please convert px to dp i have mentioned that method in answer box.

Comment: You can use Weight in place of static dp or px value for height and width.

Answer (score 1):

1. At first Rectify your **UNIT** . Use **`DP instead of PX`** .
2. Use **[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)**

> ConstraintLayout is responsible for managing the positioning and
>   sizing behavior of the visual components (also referred to as widgets)
>   it contains.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    // YOUR REST WORK

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Call**

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Thanks IntelliJ Amiya, I'll give it a try!

Comment: I changed it to DP, and changed the FrameLayout to a ConstraintLayout, but now I'm getting an error when I compile:
"Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"

Comment: @Uncle_Timothy any results ?

Comment: I'm not sure where to place "compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2''  in my Xamarin project. I did some research and apparently I put it in the .gradle file, though I don't seem to have one.

Comment: I tried installing it by going to Projects > Add NuGet Packages... > Xamarin Android Constraint Layout 1.0.2 > Add Package, but it came up with the message:

Comment: "Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout.Solver 1.0.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Answer (score 0):

To convert px to dp use this one....

```
public static int Pixel_To_DP(int pixel) {
    return (int) (pixel/ Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohd, I'll give it a try